# Fresh installation of RabbitMQ doesn't listen on port 5672 in Windows

Tags: erlang, rabbitmq

After installing RabbitMQ (rabbitmq-server-3.6.0) and Erlang (esl-erlang_18.2-1-windows_i386) I am not able to see the port `5672` in list of listening ports in by `netstat -an` command but in task manager under services category I am able to see RabbitMQ with Running status.

After installing RabbitMQ I had created two environment variables. they are:

`RABBITMQ_SERVICE` to `C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.6.0`

and

`RABBITMQ_BASE` to `C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server`

Later I reinstalled Rabbitmq and Erlang but not from scratch as I was not able to delete files completely.

Is my server up? Or is my installation wrong? Or do I have to anything in excess.

I completely have no idea on it or what is going on.

Comment: What is the result of `rabbitmqctl.bat status`? Also you can provide the result of its log files which should reside in `%RABBITMQ_BASE%\log` path.

Comment: C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.6.0\sbin>rabbitmqctl.bat

{"init terminating in do_boot",{undef,[{rabbit_misc,format,["rabbitmq-cli-~s",["
5172"]],[]},{rabbit_cli,start_distribution,0,[{file,"src/rabbit_cli.erl"},{line,
130}]},{rabbit_cli,main,3,[{file,"src/rabbit_cli.erl"},{line,52}]},{init,start_i
t,1,[{file,"init.erl"},{line,1054}]},{init,start_em,1,[{file,"init.erl"},{line,1
035}]}]}}
init terminating in do_boot ()


C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.6.0\sbin>

Comment: This is the message I am getting for both the commands `rabbitmqctl.bat` and `rabbitmqctl.bat status`

Comment: @Nagaumadevi Palaparthy. any updates?  have you resolved this issue?

Comment: @Sadaf it was resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, this was solved. I didn't have permission to install new software on my machine. Though it showed as installed successfully  because of permission issues I was not able to use the tool. once permission issues got resolved everything was fine :).

Comment: Thanks for the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

I also faced the same issue. I have got right permissions to install software. Still while installing rabbit-mq it was giving an error `Port 5672 is not listening`

After more investigation, I found that there was already running process on this port. I ran below commands:

> netstat -ano | findstr ":5672"

> taskkill /F /PID 18644

This resolved my issue.